# How to convert .Net code to vbscript?

Tags: .net, vb.net, vbscript

I need to convert This code to vbscript

```
SetAttr("C:\Users\" + Environment.UserName + "\Desktop\Client.exe", FileAttribute.Hidden)
```

Can anyone get me the above code in VBscript?

Comment: please have a look at [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the FileSystemObject. Hint: This could be googled very easily.

Example:

```
Sub HideFolderFiles(filespec)
    Dim fs, f, r 
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
    Set f = fs.GetFolder(filespec).Files
    f.attributes = 2 'hidden
End Sub
```

Source: https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28054761/VBScript-to-set-file-attributes.html

Comment: Please I need full code, How can I choose Environment.UserName path

Comment: Thanks it works,But I need only Environment.UserName Directory